# Cannot show markers in MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapbox, rubymotion

I am creating an application using RubyMotion and MapBox. I want to have an offline map with markers. I can see the map but not the marker. This is my code :

```
class MapScreen < PM::Screen

  def on_load
    RMConfiguration.configuration.setAccessToken("...")

    self.view.addSubview(map_view)

    annotation = RMPointAnnotation.alloc.initWithMapView(map_view, coordinate: map_view.centerCoordinate, andTitle: 'Hello')
    map_view.addAnnotation(annotation)
  end

  def map_view
    return @map_view if @map_view
    source = RMMBTilesSource.alloc.initWithTileSetResource('control-room-0.2.0',
      ofType:'mbtiles')
    @map_view ||= RMMapView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds, andTilesource:source).tap do |map|
      map.zoom = 2
      map.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
      map.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(0, 0))
      map.showsUserLocation = true
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work:

```
class MapScreen < PM::Screen 

    def on_load 
        RMConfiguration.configuration.setAccessToken("...")
        self.view.addSubview(map_view) 
        annotation = RMAnnotation.alloc.initWithMapView(map_view, coordinate: map_view.centerCoordinate, andTitle: 'Hello') 
        map_view.addAnnotation(annotation) 
    end 

    def map_view 
        return @map_view if @map_view 
        source = RMMBTilesSource.alloc.initWithTileSetResource('control-room-0.2.0', ofType:'mbtiles') 
        @map_view ||= RMMapView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds, andTilesource:source).tap do |map| 
            map.zoom = 4 
            map.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth 
            map.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(0, 0)) 
            map.showsUserLocation = true 
            map.delegate = self 
        end
    end  

    def mapView(map_view, layerForAnnotation:annotation) 
        image = UIImage.imageNamed('list.png') 
        RMMarker.alloc.initWithUIImage(image) 
    end 

end
```

Comment: initWithMapBoxMarkerImage seems to be undefined and MapView seems to be never triggered even if I set `map_view.delegate = self`. I am using the version 1.6.0 of MapBox.

Comment: @Dougui do you have `mapView`'s `delegate` methods list? Here it is presented: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/release/MapView/Map/RMMapViewDelegate.h

Comment: Also delegate may not trigger if you are not viewing map at the area where the annotation is located

Comment: `singleTapOnMap` seems to work. I see the should see the annotation because it's on the center.

Comment: `- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation;` is defined in `RMMapViewDelegate.h`

Comment: It is so strange that I can suggest only digging into the sources of MapBox. Delegate method should be called and marker initialisation method also should be presented, unless you are using some other MapBox sources that I mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73040/discussion-between-azat-and-dougui).